# 'Call' changing values in (%rbp)? x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I have a little problem with the following code. I move the value '10' to -8(rbp) and output it twice. First output works, but the second one gives me a strange value, but I'm not changing it anywhere:

```
.data
.comm   RCZU, 255
.text
#-8(rbp)=10
movq    %rsp, %rbp
movq    $10, %rax
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)

#output -8(rbp)
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
leaq    RCZU, %rcx
call    _conint
call    _print

#output -8(rbp)
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
leaq    RCZU, %rcx
call    _conint
call    _print

#exit
xor     %rdi, %rdi
mov     $60, %rax
syscall

#output a string with Linux syscall
_print:
leaq    RCZU(%rip), %rsi
call    _len
movq    $1, %rdi
movq    $1, %rax
syscall
ret

#convert decimal in rax to string
_conint:
xor %rsi, %rsi
cmpq    $0, %rax
jge CONINT1
neg %rax
movb    $45, (%rcx)
inc %rcx
CONINT1:
xor %rdx, %rdx
movq    $10, %rbx
divq    %rbx
addq    $48, %rdx
pushq   %rdx
inc %rsi
cmpq    $0, %rax
jz      CONINT2
jmp CONINT1
CONINT2:
cmpq    $0, %rsi
jz      CONINT3
popq    (%rcx)
inc %rcx
dec %rsi
jmp CONINT2
CONINT3:
ret

#get length of a string in (rsi) and return in rdx
_len:
pushq   %rsi
xor %rdx, %rdx
LEN1:
cmpq    $0, (%rsi)
je  LEN2
incq    %rsi
incq    %rdx
jmp LEN1
LEN2:
popq    %rsi
ret
```

Looks like the call to "_print" changes the value somehow. When I push -8(rbp) before the call and pop it afterwards, the value won't change. But is there another solution without pushing and popping it everytime?

Comment: Anyway, looking at it again you move a value to -8(RBP) but you didn't allocate space on the stack. You probably wanted to move RSP to RBP and then subtract 8 from RSP afterwards. This allocates space on the stack. By not reducing RSP the CALL instruction will push the return address on top of the stack potentially clobbering the stack data.  I'd step through with a debugger like GDB and observe where things go wrong with your code

Comment: Ah ya, now it works. Stupid me. Thank you

Comment: You can use in x86-64 the stack "red zone" (few bytes guaranteed to be preserved under `rsp`) in some OS (like linux, check the ABI definition), but only in "leaf" functions. When you `call` something further down, it will of course push return address to the stack, and also the sub-function will probably use the area under `rsp` as needed. So for "stack local variables" in non-leaf functions you have to adjust `rsp` first, to "allocate" that area.